# NodeJS Passport local authentication Is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, passport.js, passport-local

I am using **passportjs** local for authentication. It is just redirecting to the failureRedirect it doesn't show any error and it redirects always to failureRedirect with orginal username and password as well as duplicate what is the wrong in my code

my **passport.js** file:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const Admin = require('../models/admin/user');
const config = require('../config/database');

module.exports = function(passport){
    // With local startegy
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function (userName, password, done){
        // Match Username
        let query = {userName:userName};
        Admin.findOne(query, function(err, user){
            console.log(user);
            if(err) throw err;
            if(!user){
                console.log('No user Found');
                return done(null, false, {message: 'No User Found'});
            }
            // Match Password
            bcrypt.compare(password,user.password, function(err, isMatch){
                if(err) throw err;
                if(isMatch){
                    console.log('welcome to dashboard');
                    return done(null, user);
                } else {
                    console.log('Wrong Password is inserted');
                    return done(null, false, {message: 'Wrong password'});
                }
            });
        });      
    }));

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
        done(null, user.id)
    });
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
        Admin.findById(id, function(err, user){
            done(err, user);
        });
    });
}
```

**index.js** file:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const multer  = require('multer');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const config = require('./config/database');

const app = express();    
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Routes 
const admin = require('./routes/admins/a_users'); // ADMIN-Parts
const images = require('./routes/zzzimages'); // All - Images Uploading Code

// Port Number to Start 
const port = 1200;

app.use(cors());

// Body parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// view engine setup
app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));
app.engine(".hbs", exphbs({ defaultLayout: "mainlayout", extname: ".hbs", helpers: handlebarsHelpers }));
app.set("view engine", ".hbs");

// Express Session Middleware 
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: true }
  }));

 // Express Messages Middleware 
 app.use(flash());
  app.use(require('connect-flash')());
  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
     next();
});    
// Express Validator Middleware
app.use(expressValidator({
    errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value){
        var namespace = param.split('.')
        , root    = namespace.shift()
        , formParam = root;    
    while(namespace.length){
        formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
        param : formParam, msg   : msg, value : value };
    }
}));  

require('./config/passport')(passport);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use('/admin',admin); 
app.use('/allimg',images); 

app.get('/admin-login', (req, res) => {  
    res.render('admin/login');   
});
```

**users.js** file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const passport = require('passport');
const config = require('../../config/database');
const Admin = require('../../models/admin/a_user');

// login process
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect:'/psc',
        failureRedirect:'/admin-login',
        failureFlash: true
    })(req, res, next);
    console.log('login is called');

});
module.exports = router;
```

I tried with console.log as given above the route /login is called which shows login is called message but not other

Answer (score 0):

`process.exit(0);` will stop your process from running (like `die` in php or `kill` in cmd). You can try the following:

```
   passport.use("local-login", new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email

        usernameField: "email",
        passwordField: "password",
        passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    }, function (req, email, password, done) {
        var User = user;
        var Admin = models.admin;
        console.group("============================================================");
        console.log("user: "+user);
        console.log("user: "+password);
        console.groupEnd();
        var isValidPassword = function (userpass, password) {
            console.log("*********************** from isvalidpassword*****************");
            console.log(bCrypt.compareSync(password, userpass));
            return bCrypt.compareSync(password, userpass);
        };
        console.log("___________________before FindOne user.findOne_________________");
        console.log(email);
        Admin.findOne({where: { uemail: email }
        }).then(function (user) {
            if (!user) {
                console.log("Email Does not EXit");
                return done(null, false, {message: "Email does not exist"});
            }
            if (!isValidPassword(user.password, password)) {
                console.log("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$---from isValid Password---$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
                console.log("-------------user password: ", user.password );
                console.log("-------------password: ", password );
                process.exit(0);
                return done(null, false, {message: "Incorrect password."});
            }

            var userinfo = user.get();
            console.log("&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&");
            console.log(user);
            return done(null, userinfo);
        }).catch(
                function (err) {
                    console.log("Error:", err);

                    return done(null, false, {
                            message: "Something went wrong with your Signin"
                        }
                    );
                }
            );
    }
));
```